# How to get https link using URLFOR() in Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

So, I'm trying to build a link to a visualforce page in an email template and the following works... almost.

The only problem is that I'm getting a non-ssl link (http:// instead of https://)

```
<a href='{!URLFOR('/apex/SomePage', null, [id=Some_Object__c.Id,retURL="/apex/SomeOtherPage"])}'>Go to SomePage here!</a>
```

This causes the obvious problem of users having to log in to salesforce every time they click this link even if they are already logged in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround, how about

```
<a href='{!SUBSTITUTE(URLFOR('/apex/SomePage', null, [id=Some_Object__c.Id,retURL="/apex/SomeOtherPage"]),'http:','https:')}'>Go to SomePage here!</a>
```

Edit - added colons to the Substitute parameters

Comment: This should work in this case as a workaround.