# URLFOR error in Visualforce email template

Tags: email-template, urlfor

I need to change a Visualforce email template written by someone else.  They included a URLFOR in the template.  Apparently it used to work, but now when I try to view the template in Setup, there is an error

"Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: Invalid parameter for function URLFOR. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem"

I can edit and save the template, but I still see the error.

I created a basic template for testing and the same error occurs.  Has anyone else run into this?

When I create a standalone VF page with the same URLFOR syntax, it works fine.

Here is the basic email template I created.  Originally I had relatedTo.Id in place of the 111, but that didn't work either:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="test" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        {!URLFOR($Action.Case.View, '111111111111111')}
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: did you see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/how-to-get-https-link-using-urlfor-in-email-template? and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/trying-to-put-server-name-into-a-url-for-email-template ?

Comment: @crop1645 I looked at those two but they don't use $Action.

Comment: yes - but $Action.Case.View is same as `{!"\" & relatedto.id}` wrapped in an HTML `<a>` tag; That is what the links were supplying as a workaround for you